# WiFi issue in my Nokia lumia

Tags: wifi

The WiFi in my phone isnt working properly only my WhatsApp is working. None of the other apps are working. The WiFi is working properly for everyone in my house. Idk what the problem is. I tried restarting but nothing worked. Pls help

Comment: Hi ! Did you try forgetting the network and adding it again in your phone ? also, can you still access to other wifis ?

Comment: What happens if you try to use Internet Explorer?

Comment: What model and OS? I have intermittent  issues with my Lumia 950 at work, but it is fairly stable at home. I know a lot of people complain about wifi on Windows 10 mobile.